# Create LightCone (GodRays) with only light, no black, much transparencies; to place over (Alpha Over in VideoEditing) a video

Tags: shaders, light, color, compositing-nodes

[Sorry to come again with this.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215396/cant-get-transparency-right-for-god-rays)

In Blender 2.79b this works easily and perfectly by just switching on "Halo" in the "Spot" setting. Didn't even set the World's Alpha to "transparent" instead of "Sky".

Now I try to translate this into a 2.82 (oder higher) version. Tried Film->transparent for background and did a long orgy with nodes of all sorts. Material nodes for the Cone-Mesh for volumetric scattering (Node "scatter volume"), every alpha-over, keying etc.
The problem still remains: The shadows of the light cone's (I split it into several parts by a slit mask in front of the spot's light source) are rendered black and not "no light but transparent".

I enclose the (simple) blender 2.79b project here; any ideas? [MakeLightCone-2.79b](https://www.dropbox.com/s/glzxtc5rzn1abe3/MakeLightCone.blend?dl=0)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215396/cant-get-transparency-right-for-god-rays